# ruby code inside quotes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I would like to embed videos and have managed to to do so by manually coding the url in where needed.  If my url is stored in <%= @vid.url %>, how can I use that string for the value and src parameter?

```
   <object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/videos/abc123"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/videos/abc123" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of IDEs will not highlight this correctly but the ruby interpreter will automatically parse ruby before it outputs the HTML to the browser so when it is received by the browser, it will appear just as if there were a hardcoded url.  So basically, this code here:

```
<object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="<%= @vid.url %>"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="<%= @vid.url %>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object>
```

Will turn into the code that you have up there in your question when the browser receives it

Comment: Thanks.  It seems the problem is related to the youtube url rather than the html code format.

Answer (score 1):

You can just place the ERB code inside the HTML string ie. This will work:

```
value="<%= @vid.url %>"
```

When the HTML is parsed the ERB will be recognised and processed regardless of whether it is surrounded by quotation marks or not.